# cant display specific row from database using PHP though no errors is shown

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

When I click the go to the form  I want to see all other information about that id number. [image]  Here is the code behind the go to the form option:

```
        <td width="174"  class="centertext"><a href="form.php?formid=<?php echo $row["formid"]; ?>"> Go to the form</a></td>
```

This is the code that I used to retrieve a specific row from my database. the code does not show any errors but it also does not show the result.  All I see is empty page. What is the problem here? I have been trying to solve for 1 week and can't find anything.   I am beginner at PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","son_fbe");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
exit();

    }


$formid = isset($_GET['formid ']) ? $_GET['formid '] : ''; 

    if($sql= "SELECT formid,gonderilen,gonderen FROM derssaydirma WHERE formid = ?")
                  {  
                     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                     $stmt->bind_param("i", $formid);
                     $stmt->execute();
                     $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                         echo $row[ 'formid'];   
                         echo  $row['gonderilen'];
                         echo $row['gonderen'];   }

                     $stmt->close();
                 }
                 // show an error if the query has an error
                 else
                 {
                     echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
                 }


?>
```

Comment: Your `if` statement will never be false. All it's checking is the assignment of a string to `$sql`.

Comment: what do you mean?  I do not get it

Comment: What do you think this line does? `if($sql= "SELECT formid,gonderilen,gonderen FROM derssaydirma WHERE formid = ?")`

Comment: it will take three columns that mentioned there  where the formid is met and  İf it takes these 3 columns do the following statements. is it right?

Comment: But what is the purpose of wrapping it inside an `if`?

Comment: Actually  I do not know.  when you say it, it looks there is no need for if statement.

Comment: Are you sure there are any rows returned at all? Maybe your query is wrong and there are no results at all. Can you do a echo inside the while and check if something gets print?

Comment: @davidev    Yeah there is no result. I already do the echo here. while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                         echo $row[ 'formid'];   
                         echo  $row['gonderilen'];
                         echo $row['gonderen'];   }

Comment: Tip: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so errors resulting from simple mistakes made aren’t easily ignored. Without exceptions you must pay close attention to return values, many of these indicate problems you must resolve or report to the user. Exceptions allow for more sophisticated flow control as they can “bubble up” to other parts of your code where it’s more convenient to handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the mistake.. you having a blank inside your name when accessing the get array. `$formid` will be "" and that's why your query is not working.

Change this line..

```
$formid = isset($_GET['formid ']) ? $_GET['formid '] : '';
```

to

```
$formid = isset($_GET['formid']) ? $_GET['formid'] : '';
```

Comment: @dontclosemyquestions No problem .. I tried to reproduce your code and then noticed that $formid is "" eventhough I set the get parameter